# How do I map my divs to links based on unique ids in jquery?

Tags: jquery

For this html:

```
<a href="#" id="link-23">User 23</a>
<a href="#" id="link-24">User 24</a>

<div id="user-23">Bob</div>
<div id="user-24">Tim</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write a script (using jquery) to toggle visibility of `div#user-23` when `a#link-23` is clicked?

**NOTE:** I'm coding in Rails and the above code is the html output of my script. I'm using an iterator in my script to create these divs and links.

Comment: It would probably be better to create your links like `<a href="#user23">User 23</a>` then you could just take the href and select the div with it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that HTML I'd suggest:

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        $('#' + this.id.replace('link', 'user')).toggle();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VFq9J/).

If you use the `href` attribute, though, to target the relevant elements you could just use CSS (in compliant browsers at least):

```
<a href="#user-23" id="link-23">User 23</a>
<a href="#user-24" id="link-24">User 24</a>

<div id="user-23">Bob</div>
<div id="user-24">Tim</div>​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VFq9J/1/).

References:

- [Compatibility information for `:target` pseudo-selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t316).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Wow! Calling .replace() here is smart!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var n = this.id.match(/\d+/g).join('');
   $('#user-' + n).toggle(); 
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kEP4d/

Comment: At last I learned how regex works in jquery. I had been desperately googling to find out.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$("a[id^='link']").each(function() {
      $(this).click(function() {
          var idnum=$(this).attr("id").replace("link-", "");
          $("div#user-"+idnum).toggle();
      });
  });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SHdhr/23/)